# Which kart, wheel and glider in Mario Kart 7 have the largest acceleration?

Tags: mario-kart-7

I haven't unlocked all of the parts and I want to know which ones have the highest acceleration. Which ones do?

Comment: What does deem mean?

Comment: @Ben the question in your comment has been heavy edited multiple times completing changing the original purpose of the question and Frank suggested to as a new one

Comment: @Memor-X Fair enough, Just saw the two questions and jumped to a conclusion. Now I look silly :P

Comment: Don't forget to delete the other question, as Frank suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts having the highest acceleration statistic are the following:

1. Karts (each of them having 3.50 in acceleration):

   - Birthday Girl
   - Bumble V
   - Egg 1
2. Wheels (+0.75 in acceleration):

   - Roller
3. Gliders (those are the light gliders with +0.25 acceleration):

   - Flower
   - Paraglider
   - Parasol
   - Swooper

Comment: I'm guessing Birthday Girl is Royal Ribbon in my country..?

Comment: The name is different depending on the region, Birthday Girl(Japanese/American) Royal Ribbon(European)